Flutter app not launchig after using deep link command
I'm using GoRouter and following the steps of this tutorial to enable deep linking in the app.
The deep links are appearing in the devtool, so i think my site is setup correctly. However, when testing with
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "http://<web-domain>/details"'

It does not launch my app. My manifest looks like this :
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="my.website" android:pathPattern=".*" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="my.website" android:pathPattern=".*" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="my.second.website" android:pathPattern=".*" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="my.second.website" android:pathPattern=".*" />
</intent-filter>

Where should i start looking to debug this ? It looks like the app setup is broken, because the command tests only the app side of deep linking.

I think simply you just miss the <package name> in your command test

